# Is there a problem with my Javascript/HTML code or with Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to connect a JavaScript document to an HTML document. Sublime isn't showing the right recognition of the .style.display (it's supposed to be blue, it's showing white, as shown).

What is wrong with my code? Or is there something missing in my Sublime? Is there a package I have to download?

For more reference, both files are in a folder called "js" on my Mac's desktop.

[image: HTML Code]
[image: Javascript Code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: This question was purely about the color scheme so posting pictures was probably ok. However this is not a question about javascript or HTML but purely about sublimetext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime has different colour schemes for different languages. In your first image you have HTML-markup and in the second it's JavaScript. There's nothing wrong with either the code nor your Sublime setup.

Although one thing that might a problem, if both the HTML and JS files are in the same folder you don't need to reference from `Desktop/js/script.js`, you can just reference `script.js` in the script-tag.

Comment: @thenabh if this answers your question you should consider to upvote it and accept it. you can upvote multiple questions but you can only accept one. You can always change your decision tho.

Comment: Thanks! I'm super new. But did so.